# In Deque, difference between remove() and pop()

Tags: java, collections, linked-list, queue, deque

This code:

```
    Deque<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.push("first");
    list.push("second");
    list.push("third");
    
    System.out.println(list.remove());
```

Is equivalent to:

```
    Deque<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.push("first");
    list.push("second");
    list.push("third");
    
    System.out.println(list.pop());
```

Both pop() and remove() remove the first element (head). So, what's the reason for having two different methods?

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with legacy interfaces. From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html):

*Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This interface should be used in preference to the legacy Stack class. When a deque is used as a stack, elements are pushed and popped from the beginning of the deque. Stack methods are precisely equivalent to Deque methods as indicated in the table below:*

*Comparison of Stack and Deque methods*

`Stack Method | Equivalent Deque Method`
`push(e)      | addFirst(e)`
`pop()        | removeFirst()`
`peek()       | peekFirst()`

Comment: could we add a little more description? how about for "remove" ? I only see removeFirst aobve cc @VGR

Comment: @mattsmith5 The javadoc link is a page that contains more tables, including a table that shows that remove(), just like pop(), is equivalent to removeFirst().  I suppose this answer *could* include all of those tables, but copying an entire class description from the documentation seems redundant.